# Disable click event propagation on construct 2 html canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, construct-2

I have a construct 2 game export file, in which I append a html file on top of it. I want to disable the on touch/click event of the dynamically generated canvas of the construct 2 game because when I click on the appended html, the click also propagates to the canvas element of the game.

I have used event.stopPropagation() and event.preventDefault() functions, but to no avail.

Comment: event.stopPropagation() seems to be correct approach for this scenario. Can you share code so we can see what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Use only css as `pointer-events: none;`

```js
function func(){
console.log("clicked");
}
```

```css
#myCanvas{
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    pointer-events: none;
}
#myCanvas2{
 border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<h2>With Css try to click me..</h2>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100" onclick="func()">
</canvas>


<h2>Without Css try to click me..</h2>
<canvas id="myCanvas2" width="200" height="100" onclick="func()">
</canvas>
```

Comment: The problem is that the canvas is being dynamically generated from the construct 2 editor. So it is not convenient for me to add any class or id to the canvas and add a pointer event.

P.S. Pointer events to none did not work

Answer (score 0):

Add in the css property `pointer-events: none`

Answer (score 0):

If it's only Construct2 problem I would say add condition to every on click event that checks if the cursor is NOT over HTML element to activate canvas events, and not activate if it is. Since I'm not quite sure where the problem occurs I'll leave it at that, hope it helps!